# Is it possible to execute nested ajax on click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using nested ajax in my code and wanted to execute it on click of a button. but when I try to add any event listener inner ajax never gets success. when I remove on click event or event listener it works fine.

```js
$("#Id1").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'url1',
    type: 'get',
    data: {
      method: 'method1',
      id: id1
    },
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function(a) {
      console('ajax1');
      if (a == 1) {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'url2',
          type: 'post',
          data: {
            arg1: p,
            arg2: q
          },
          datatype: 'json',
          success: function(b) {
            console('ajax2');
          }
        }
        else {
          alert('hello');
        }
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This code fails and never executes success part of inner ajax. whereas code mentioned below works fine.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'url1',
  type: 'get',
  data: {
    method: 'method1',
    id: id1
  },
  datatype: 'json',
  success: function(a) {
    console('ajax1');
    if (a == 1) {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'url2',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
          arg1: p,
          arg2: q
        },
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(b) {
          console('ajax2');
        }
      }
      else {
        alert('hello');
      }
    }
  });
```

Can somebody please help me on this? I am very to new to ajax and javascript. I tried putting error and failure inside second ajax but it do not enter in that callbacks.

Comment: Firstly, it's `$.ajax({ /* settings */ });`, not `$.ajax() {...`. However I assume this is just a typo in the question as it wouldn't work in either case if that really was your code. Therefore logic would dictate that the problem is your click handler, not the AJAX requests. Have you debugged the handler to ensure it's been added, and is attached to the correct element? I'd suggest you open devtools and check for errors in your code, and also the outcome of the request in the network tab

Comment: It's possible, but it's called a callback hell and it's ugly, and difficult to read, understand and maintain. Look up how to avoid callback hells.

Comment: Just before `$("#Id1").click` what does `console.log($("#Id1").length)` output to the console?  I'm guessing a nice clear `0`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes, Im sorry its a typo in question.

Comment: @freedomn-m I tried console.log($("#Id1").length) before $("#Id1").click just like you said and it was 1.

Comment: The fact that they are nested is irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: @KevinB well yes. I am able to get inside first ajax and it also goes inside second ajax call performs the operation but do not come back in success block. dont know why??

Comment: Probably because it wasn't successful. Have you checked to see what error it is returning?

Comment: It is successful without click event. what difference does the click event made?

Comment: I added error callback but not able to get inside that too.

Comment: Where is `id1` defined in each case and what's its value (check with code *inside* the click event)

Comment: What is this thing you are clicking? Is it causing any extra side effects, like a postback?

Comment: Its working now, it just worked by adding e inside click and e.preventDefault() just before the first ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got that working just by doing this:

```
$("#Id1").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
url: 'url1',
type: 'get',
data: {
  method: 'method1',
  id: id1
},
datatype: 'json',
success: function(a) {
  console('ajax1');
  if (a == 1) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'url2',
      type: 'post',
      data: {
        arg1: p,
        arg2: q
      },
      datatype: 'json',
      success: function(b) {
        console('ajax2');
      }
    }
    else {
      alert('hello');
    }
  }
});
```

});